# pkg load sockets with octave

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, octave, package

I have installed octave on Ubuntu 16.04 originally without the ppa (version 4.0.0), but the problem remains with the ppa (version 4.0.2).

To install it, I have runned : `sudo apt install octave octave-sockets` and it went fine.

But when I am in octave-cli and I run this command: `pkg load sockets`. I have the following error:

`error: __which__: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/sockets-1.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/socket.oct: failed to load: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/sockets-1.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/socket.oct: undefined symbol: _ZNK5ArrayISsE17resize_fill_valueEv
error: called from
    which at line 31 column 7
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/sockets-1.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/PKG_ADD at line 2 column 1
    load_packages_and_dependencies at line 47 column 5
    load_packages at line 60 column 3
    pkg at line 422 column 7
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
error: called from
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/sockets-1.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/PKG_ADD at line 2 column 1
    load_packages_and_dependencies at line 47 column 5
    load_packages at line 60 column 3
    pkg at line 422 column 7`

So I am supposing that the package octave-sockets is missing a dependency but I don't find which one. If you can help me with that... Thank you very much!

Comment: Similar to [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300259). Try using `pkg install -forge sockets` instead

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. You can post the answer if you want. Or do I?

Comment: @Suever well well, what brings you to the octave neighbourhood? _*cracks open a beer_*

Comment: @onda47 in general, you'll have the most straightforward experience if you [compile the latest stable version of octave from source](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installation.html) (and install packages via -forge as Suever suggested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using Ubuntu's packaged `octave-sockets` package, you're likely to have a better experience if you install the package directly from Octave instead

```
pkg install -forge sockets
```